# Machine learning, applying training model to testing

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Political science grad student who is way over his head (ambitious but rubbish as they say). Basically, I am trying to do an attractiveness prediction on a set of politicians for political science purposes. I followed this [guide](https://www.learnopencv.com/computer-vision-for-predicting-facial-attractiveness/).

Having extracted landmarks and generated features, I have used my learning set (CFD, 400 images with ratings) for a model predicts ratings that correlate 0.49 (good enough for my purposes) with actual ratings through cross validation. This is that code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import linear_model
features = np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\bruker\\Desktop\\Data\\CFD_features.txt', delimiter=',')
ratings = np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\bruker\\Desktop\\Data\\CFD_ratings.txt', delimiter=',')
predictions = np.zeros(ratings.size);

for i in range(0, 400):
    features_train = np.delete(features, i, 0)
    features_test = features[i, :]
    ratings_train = np.delete(ratings, i, 0)
    ratings_test = ratings[i]
    pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=13)
    pca.fit(features_train)
    features_train = pca.transform(features_train)
    features_test = pca.transform(features_test)
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(features_train, ratings_train)
    predictions[i] = regr.predict(features_test)
    print 'number of models trained:', i+1

np.savetxt('C:\\Users\\bruker\\Desktop\\Data\\CFDN_cross_valid_predictions.txt', predictions, delimiter=',', fmt = '%.04f')

corr = np.corrcoef(predictions, ratings)[0, 1]
print corr
```

Now I have a another features.txt with feature data for politicians (142 images), for which I have no ratings. What I am trying to do is use the training set/model constructed by the forgoing code to generate predicted attractiveness ratings for my politicians, but I have absolutely no idea how to proceed. The guide is silent on this, probably because its intended for people who know Python :).  I've spent a lot of hours trying to figure out ways to modify/build this code to make it happen, but my lack of Python/general coding knowledge makes it very hard to figure out.

Given the significant brainpower and knowledge on this site I am hoping someone knows a solution and could help me out. Apologies for my cluelessness, and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Its pretty easy. You do the same steps as above, but not calling `fit()` on `pca` or `regr`. Just only call `pca.transform()` and `regr.predict()` on your new data. But for that you need to keep the objects `pca` and `regr` persistant. You should explain your code more like what the `for i in range(0, 400):` is doing and I maybe help writing the code for it.

Comment: Thanks for you response. So as far as I have gathered (I did not write this code). The i in range is that it loops it 400 times. So for image 1 it uses the other 399 images to train and then predicts images 1, then it does image 2, and uses the other 399 images to train and predict its rating. Now I don't think I need that, since what I want to do is use the 400 images that have ratings that I used in this code to predict the other 142 images I have that do not have ratings for. I am just unsure how to disentangle the code to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the for loop, it becomes pretty easy.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import linear_model

features_train = np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\bruker\\Desktop\\Data\\CFD_features.txt', delimiter=',')
ratings_train = np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\bruker\\Desktop\\Data\\CFD_ratings.txt', delimiter=',')

pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=13)
pca.fit(features_train)
features_train = pca.transform(features_train)
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(features_train, ratings_train)

features_test = np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\bruker\\Desktop\\Data\\CFD_features_Test.txt', delimiter=',')

features_test = pca.transform(features_test)
predictions = regr.predict(features_test)
```

Comment: Just had to do some minor tweaks and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much Vivek!